# Concourse resource cache flushing

Tags: concourse

Sometimes when a concourse pipeline is getting build, it tries to use the previous version of resource, not the latest one. I could confirm this because the resource hash don't match.
Please let me know a solution to flush the resource hash.

Answer (score 4):

Concourse v7.4.0 (released August 2021) adds the command

```
fly clear-resource-cache -r <pipeline>/<resource>
```

which will do what you are looking for.

See:

- the documentation for [clear-resource-cache](https://concourse-ci.org/managing-resources.html#fly-clear-resource-cache).
- the [release notes](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/tag/v7.4.0) for v7.4.0

Comment: Any idea on how to do this for earlier versions? My company is on an older version so I can't use this command.

Comment: @rup: see the other answer to the question.

Comment: For the older version I was able to use fly -t ci clear-task-cache

Answer (score 1):

The only way to flush the resource cache is to restart all the workers, as this will clear your ephemeral disks.

Comment: Ohh.. c**p.. I thought this is the last option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `fly clear-resource-cache -r <pipeline>/<resource>` command doesn't work for older versions.

To achieve similar results, you can use

```
fly -t ci clear-task-cache -j <pipeline>/<resource> -s <step-name>
```

Check the help command for more info:

```
Usage:
  fly [OPTIONS] clear-task-cache [clear-task-cache-OPTIONS]

Application Options:
  -t, --target=              Concourse target name
  -v, --version              Print the version of Fly and exit
      --verbose              Print API requests and responses
      --print-table-headers  Print table headers even for redirected output

Help Options:
  -h, --help                 Show this help message

[clear-task-cache command options]
      -j, --job=             Job to clear cache from
      -s, --step=            Step name to clear cache from
      -c, --cache-path=      Cache directory to clear out
      -n, --non-interactive  Destroy the task cache(s) without confirmation
```

Answer (score 0):

**For resources:**

```
fly -t example clear-resource-cache -r my-pipeline/my-resource
```

[Corresponding documenation link](https://concourse-ci.org/managing-resources.html#fly-clear-resource-cache).

**For tasks:**
I've tested this on 7.9.1 (fairly recently as of this post - about 3 weeks ago).

```
fly -t demo clear-task-cache --job java-api-pipeline/compile-app-task --step task1
```

To see this in action see the online course "
Getting Started with Concourse CI" on Pluralsight, Module 4: Composing and Managing Pipelines, Clip 4: Demo: Running and Managing Pipelines.

[Corresponding documentation link](https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#fly-clear-task-cache).

Answer (score 0):

If there are job(s) in the pipeline that are supposed to be executed before the job you're executing, then it might be the cache regardless of the check_every setting for the resource.
Just restart the jobs on the dependencies and it will be refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

As of the time of this writing 2023-06-21, the command to clear the cache requires a target, so:

```
fly -t <target> clear-resource-cache -r <pipeline>/<resource>
```

Sample:

```
fly -t demo destroy-pipeline -p java-api-pipeline
```